# Flask raises TemplateNotFound error, despite recognizing correct directory when using EXPLAIN_TEMPLATE_LOADING config

Tags: python, html, flask

I am attempting to render the file `login.html` The file exists in my project, inside the proper template folder. However, I still get the `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: login.html` error, upon attempting to run my code.

In an effort to understand the cause of the issue, I made the explain template loading config true. The following was spit out when I ran it again.

```
    1: trying loader of application "__main__"
   class: jinja2.loaders.FileSystemLoader
   encoding: 'utf-8'
   followlinks: False
   searchpath:
     - /home/rbob/flask-application/templates
   -> no match
```

For whatever reason, it still cannot locate login.html, despite it going to the folder which contains login.html.

How could I fix this issue? This error only occurs on Linux Mint. The code runs without issues on windows 10.

Comment: I can't tell by looking at the current info what the problem may be, please provide us with more information, i.e. application structure tree and your route where you call the `render_template` function.

Comment: The structure is as follows.                                                                                                            /flask-application                                                                                                                           
      /flask-env

Comment: The structure is as follows.                                                                                                            /flask-application                                                                                                                           
      /flask-env                                                                                                                    
      /server.py                                                                                                                  
      /Templates (Has all html files under it)

Comment: Use the `tree` command in your terminal and then output the result

Comment: Can you reduce your app to a small sample that demonstrates the problem, and then post that? Without seeing code, we can only speculate.

Comment: Maybe a obvious solution but have you checked the spelling of `templates`?